# is it realistically possible to make this game in HTML5+Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Using the Canvas element and JavaScript is it realistically possible to create a 2d sidescroller that has playable content for around 1 hour? With content I mean cutscenes, dialogue and of course, combat.  I'm asking this because I've only seen Demo's or really small games that have been made with different library's (such as ImpactJS). JavaScript is single threaded too (correct me if i'm wrong) so that'd make it even harder.. I'm not really worried about browser incompatibility, as long as 1 browser can run it it's fine.

**In short/TL;DR, is game dev in jscript/html5 developed far enough to handle more than mini-games(such as canabalt, doodle jump, etc), and also, graphics wise, is canvas capable of processing (higher)detailed images (as in, not pixelart)?**

Comment: Yes. As long as it progressively (lazy) loads resources and releases them regularly, shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Just as an example whats possible: http://www.unrealengine.com/html5/

Comment: @MarcelGwerder Doesn't support Chrome? How crappy can something be that it doesn't work in Chrome?

Comment: @JuanMendes It's because it's in a very early stage and they have been working together with mozilla. When you download the nightly build of firefox 23 and test it you will see that this is maybe as good as it can get at the moment.

Comment: JavaScript can be multiple threaded with https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Using_web_workers. You can only access the DOM from the main thread though

Comment: That is amazing. @Juan Mendes Thanks for that link!

Comment: I think this is a constructive/valid question.  Possibly better on programmers.

Comment: @djechlin You should be able to tell what the question is from the title. If your title says "is this possible... to do this", it's a not a good fit for SO, and it's poorly asked and it's multiple questions embedded in one.

Comment: @Juan Mendes, this is all nice and good in theory but some concepts require a larger explanation and do not necessarily need a conclusive answer, but more of a take on things, examples of something, etc. My tl:dr is too large for a title and yet it still doesn't fully cover what I wanted to ask

Comment: @AlainBruno I didn't mean that it's a bad question. It's just not a good fit for stack overflow. Like djechlin said, http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ is a better place for open ended questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the Quake 2 Port that was done completely using HTML5/JS/Web GL.

[quake2-gwt-port](https://code.google.com/p/quake2-gwt-port/)

If the combination can handle Quake 2, I think a 2D side scroller should be reasonable.